# Calling oracle package from SSRS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, plsql, ssrs-2008

I want to send the date range and employee ids from SSRS to Oracle package. Does anyone knows how to do it? Even if i try to declare an oracle package with three in parameters from_date, to_date and employee_id it works fine with one employee id. But fails if i select multiple employees in SSRS web interface saying wrong number of parameters. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally with SQL and SSRS you would do something like

`Select * From Table where Table.Field in @Param`

Oracle is different of course and depends on the Connection Type you are using.

ODBC connection you would use something like:
`Select * From Table where Table.Field = ?`
Order of the parameters is important here so be careful.

OLEDB connection you would use something like: 
`Select * From Table where Table.Field = :Param`

However, none of the above work with multi selecting of the Parameters. You could do this:

`=”Select * From Table where Table.Field in (‘” + Join(Parameters!parameter.Value,”‘, ‘”) + “‘)”`

or

`=”Select * From Table where Table.Field in(” + Join(Parameters!parameter.Value,”, “) + “)”` if the values or your field is only numeric.

Here are a couple of good articles that you can look at. It has a better explanation than I can give personally without more information; Details of your Oracle Environment, Connection Type, etc.

[Quick Reference:](http://arcanecode.com/2008/10/20/sql-server-reporting-services-oracle-and-multivalued-parameters/)

> 1. Be sure your Oracle version is 9 or greater, none of this works on
>      versions 8 or older.
> 2. When using parameters with Oracle, use a : instead of an @ sign –
>      :param instead of @param.
> 3. Add an ‘ALL’ option to your datasets that supply values for
>      multivalued drop down parameters.
> 4. Check for the ALL in your where clause by using “where ( field1 in (
>      :prmField1 ) or ‘ALL’ in ( :prmField1 ) )” syntax.
> 5. You can execute your query from the dataset window, but can only
>      supply 1 value. However that value can be ‘ALL’.
> 6. Educate your users on ‘ALL’ versus ‘(select all)’ .

Another good article about Multiple Parameters in SSRS with Oracle: [Davos Collective](http://davoscollective.com/2013/multivalue-parameters-in-ssrs/)  Which is referenced in the top portion.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm using OLEDB hence :Param is used. Oracle DB is 11g. But how to pass parameter to oracle procedure? My procedure is test_package.test_proc(start_date, end_date, employee_id). If i select multiple values for employee_id when i call procedure directly in data set, it starts crashing saying number of parameters don't match. Am i calling package wrongly? What i'm doing is in data set calling it like this test_package.test_proc(:start_date, :end_date, :employee_id) in datasource of type TEXT, i'm not using PROCEDURE in dataset. Is it wrong?

Comment: @shady You should check out this article. It approaches the problem a bit differently: http://www.joellipman.com/articles/microsoft/sql-server/ssrs/559-returning-oracle-stored-procedure-resultset-in-ssrs.html It as you create a cursor within SSRS to loop through the data. Should do what you are wanting if the above (in the quoted text) did not work.